# Does every vector of arbitrary dimension have an orthogonal vector?

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose I have at my disposal, a non zero vector $v$ of dimension $N>1$ with complex coefficients. $N$ can be any number possible, so long as it makes sense mathematically.

Now I claim, that for any possible $v$ of any possible $N$, I can always find another non zero vector $u$ of dimension $N$ such that they are orthogonal.

$$u•v=0$$

Is my claim true and if not, to what extent is it false ie, only true if dimension is a positive integer less than infinity and/or values of coeficients must be real?

And can I also perhaps have a proof of it if possible?

Comment: Are you familiar with inner products?

Comment: Hint: if $v, w$ are linearly independent, then consider $u = v - \frac{w \cdot v}{\|v\|^2}v$.

Comment: @Theo Benefit yes I am. The reason I'm asking is because I'm not sure this property holds when $N$ is infinitely large. And also I'm not sure about non integer values, which apparently exists.

Comment: In infinitely many dimensions, you can find $2$ linearly independent vectors (if you couldn't, then either your space is trivial, or after choosing one non-zero vector, every other vector is in its span, hence the space is $1$-dimensional). You can then use the formula above to construct an orthogonal, non-zero vector to $v$.

Comment: It's worth stressing that in the case of an infinite dimensional space there isn't necessarily an obvious inner product.

Comment: That formula should be $w - \frac{w \cdot v}{\|v\|^2} v$ of course!

Answer (score 1):

For $N>1$ this is possible. Suppose $v$ is only non-zero in one coordinate, then let $m$ be such that $v_{m}=0$ and pick $u=(u_{n})$ where $u_{n}=0$ if $n\neq m$ and $n=1$ if $n=m$. If $v$ is non-zero in at least two coordinates let $k,m$ be such that $v_{k}\neq 0$ and $v_{m}\neq 0$. Let $u=(u_{n})$ where $u_{n}=0$ if $n\neq m,k$, $u_{n}=1$ if $n=k$ and $u_{n}=-\frac{v_{k}}{v_{m}}$ if $n=m$.

Answer (score 1):

When $N>1$ is a natural number the answer is yes. First, for simplicity, I'm assuming that by $u\circ v$ you mean the standard inner product:
$$u\circ v = \sum_{i=1}^Nu_i\overline{v_i}.$$
Then we can prove this claim by induction. The base case is when $N=2$: Let $(u_1,u_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2$. If $u_2=0$ take $v=(0,1)$; otherwise take $v=(1,\frac{\overline{u_1}}{\overline{u_2}})$.
Now, suppose the claim holds for $N$, and let $u = (u_1,\ldots,u_{N+1}) \in \mathbb{C}^{N+1}$. If $(u_1,\ldots,u_N) \neq 0$ then by the assumption there exists some $0 \neq (v_1,\ldots,v_N) \in \mathbb{C}^N$ orthogonal to it in $\mathbb{C}^N$; we may then take $v = (v_1,\ldots,v_N,0)$. Otherwise, we may take $v = (1,0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb{C}^{N+1}$.

Comment: Then for non natural numbers?

Comment: @Horus You mean in the case that the vector space isn't of finite dimension? In this case you need to specify the inner product explicitly. For example, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i\overline{v_i}$ is not finite for all choices of $u,v \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: At any rate it is true that for any inner product space $H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ of dimension $2$ or more and any $0 \neq u \in H$, there exists $0 \neq v \in H$ s.t. $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an inner product space $X$ of dimension greater than or equal to $2$ (including, possibly, infinite dimensional), and $v \in X$.

Suppose first that $v = 0$. Then any non-zero $u \in X$ will suffice, and one must exist because otherwise $\dim X = 0$ by definition.

Otherwise, suppose $v \neq 0$. Suppose there wasn't some $w \in X$ such that $\{v, w\}$ was linearly independent. Then there exists some scalar $\alpha$ such that $w = \alpha v$. In other words, $w \in \operatorname{span} \{v\}$, which means $\{v\}$ spans $X$. Since $v \neq 0$, it is linearly independent, and hence is a basis for $X$. That is, $\dim X = 1$, which is a contradiction.

So, for this linearly independent $w$, construct
$$u = w - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle}v.$$
Then
$$\langle u, v\rangle = \langle w, v \rangle - \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle} \langle v, v \rangle = 0.$$

All we need to do is check that $u \neq 0$. If $u = 0$, then this would imply $\{ v, w \}$ is linearly dependent. This cannot be the case, by construction, so $u \neq 0$ and $u \perp v$.